# .get() is double counting a character at the end of a file

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string file;
    cout << "Please enter input file name: ";
    cin >> file;

    int count[128] = {0};

    ifstream in(file.c_str());

    char one;
    cin >> noskipws;

    while(!in.eof()){
        in.get(one);
        count[static_cast<int>(one)]++;

        cout << one << " : " << static_cast<int>(one) << endl;
    }
}
```

For an input file of:

```
Hello.
Line 2
```

My program tells me that there are two 2's at the end of the file. Why is this? To be clear, this is what I output:

```
H : 72
e : 101
l : 108
l : 108
o : 111
. : 46

 : 10
L : 76
i : 105
n : 110
e : 101
  : 32
2 : 50
2 : 50
```

Which is what I want besides for the two 2's at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be like this

```
while(in.get(one)){
       count[static_cast<int>(one)]++;
       cout << one << " : " << static_cast<int>(one) << endl;
}
```

It should resolve your problem with doubling end number.

Comment: duplicating the input code to work around the erroneous use of `.eof()` gets pretty ugly if the input code is more than a simple `.get()`. Besides, this is still failing to check if the first `.get()` failed.

Comment: Yes, you're right (Cubbi), I hope I fixed the problems you mentioned.

Comment: just one more step to the normal C++ input loop `while(in.get(one))`

Comment: Ok, I surrender. Can you tell me how this loop will end and why. Because a can't understand how returning EOF from .get() will end it.

Comment: the duplicate question's [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/273767) has an explanation